How turn off the screen verification on macbook pro 2019
The screen of MacbookPro 2019 is broken, but I don't want to replace it now for economic reasons (external works well enough).
As you may see the screen works just fine (despite on the broken pixels) either in Recovery Mode or in ordinary usage.


But the issue is that when Im logging it in - (as I assume) the OS verifies the screen for damage and just turns it off (see the gif) as it gets ready.

As next step I plan to use SwitchResX to crop the dead pixels
I wish to configure the screen a bit to keep it using it as secondary screen (an external monitor will be the 1st one). Meanwhile the external display works fine with this mac after logging in.
Can I force the screen to work all the time (after the OS log in)?

The computer isn’t verifying the screen; the graphics hardware loads in a low-performance “compatibility mode” initially and then loads pipeline code with texture acceleration to take full advantage of the rendering hardware (possibly increasing refresh rate as well).
As you mention, this does have a benefit to let you log in to the OS and get it connected to network in case you can remote in and work or back things up from a screen sharing or ssh session.
I’m not aware of a way to keep the GPU in basic mode. But perhaps there’s a hack for that to alter the OS or the GPU drivers.
Keep good backups as this sort of hardware failure could cascade to the entire graphics pipeline if a trace shorts and overloads the GPU or the power supply.

yeah, thanks for advice to keep backups, because I didnt think it could fail cascadingly

Also @AlexeyNikonov you might be seeing the firmware showing a pre boot screen when it works and none of the OS attempts can render anything meaningful. I do hope someone else has experience modifying the GPU and can squeak more life out of that screen. Being frugal is awesome with older hardware.

I just got an idea: to pull the display board flex cable out from the motherboard to prevent the trace shorts and GPU failure in the future (I nothing lose having the int. and ext. monitors mirrored). What do think on it?

If the system boots without the display, it might be good. I think it’s very rare the damage could spread, as I’ve seen machines run for years with damage like yours, but you won’t care if you suffer an unlikely failure and others get away with it.
